# how to use non-target attributes for timeseries prediction in weka?

Tags: time-series, weka, forecasting

i have used the weka timeseries plugin w/ algorithms like SMOReg (w/ RegSMOImproved and RegSMO) and HoltWinters. But for all of them i've observed that lag variables are created only for target attributes.

how does one have lag variables created for other (non-target) attributes such that the algo uses these too?

eg: i have 5 attributes ", a, b, c, d"
of which i have to predict for "a". ie. "a" is the "target" attribute
i've observed that lag variables are created only for "date" and "a" and that *none* of b, c or d are used by the algorithms

note that "overlay" does not really help me because i don't have "future" values for either of b, c or d

what i need is that lag variables be created for b, c and d and they be used for prediction by the chosen algorithm

==================== update ====================

i tried the following approach:

1. use the "filters->unsupervised->Copy" filter to make multiple (14) copies of the a,b,c,d variables
2. use "filters->unsupervised->TimesSeriesDelta" filter to shift the copies by consecutive values (eg, 1st copy by 1 day, 2nd copy by 2 days, ... 14th copy by 14 days)
3. use SMOReg from "classify" panel (w/ %-split of 70%) instead of from "forecast" panel (w/ .3 hold out training evaluation)

but faced the following barriers:
1. can classify (regress, actually, since the target is numeric) only 1 variable at a time
2. did not accept "date" attribute (even though the "date" values are numeric 20150601, 20150602, 20150603, and so on)
3. ran for a long time and then crashed :(

any guidance will be greatly appreciated

ps: the above example is contrived. in my real example, i have date + 8 attributes (all of them numeric), and 3 of them are target (multivariate forecasting)

==================== update ====================

https://github.com/log0ymxm/weka-timeseriesforecasting/blob/master/src/main/java/weka/classifiers/timeseries/core/TSLagMaker.java#L2974

shows that the extra attributes (non-target) are being removed because (line #3027 says):

```
// otherwise, this is some attribute that we are not predicting and
// wont be able to determine the value for when forecasting future
// instances. So we can't let the model use it.
```

==================== update ====================

https://github.com/log0ymxm/weka-timeseriesforecasting/blob/master/src/main/java/weka/classifiers/timeseries/WekaForecaster.java#L576

shows that fields-to-lag are same as fields-to-forecast

Answer (score 0):

from the last 2 updates, i found that:

1. non-target attributes are removed
2. only target attributes are lagged

i thought this was algorithm specific (eg. HoltWinters, etc), but it's a feature/bug of timesseriesForecasting plugin itself

basically what i want isn't possible without code change :(